# Merging two dictionaries with nested arrays

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries

```
a = {'I': [1,2], 'II': [1,2], 'III': [1,2]}
b = {'I': [3,4], 'II': [3,4], 'IV': [3,4]}
```

how can i merge them such that i get the following result

```
c = merge_dicts(a,b)
```

where c is `{'I': [1,2,3,4], 'II': [1,2,3,4], 'III': [1,2], 'IV': [3,4]}`

Is there a good pythonic way of doing this?

Note that I am a python newbie, even though I am using words like pythonic. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need ALL values:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

a = {'I': [1,2], 'II': [1,2], 'IV': [1,2]}
b = {'I': [3,4], 'II': [3,4], 'V': [3,4]}

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in chain(a.iteritems(), b.iteritems()):
    d[key].extend(value)
d
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'I': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'II': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'V': [3, 4], 'IV': [1, 2]})
```

Comment: +1 this solution is the only one till now which works for Python 2.5

Comment: And FWIW, to remove the "default" behavior from your dict after creating it, you could set `d.default_factory = None`.  Then it starts behaving like a regular dict again.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure they have the same keys?  You could do:

```
c = dict( (k,a[k]+b[k]) for k in a )
```

Addition of lists concatenates so `a[k] + b[k]` gives you something like `[1,2]+[3,4]` which equals `[1,2,3,4]`.  The `dict` constructor can take a series of 2-element iterables which turn into `key` - `value` pairs.

If they don't share the keys, you can use `set`s.

```
aset = set(a)
bset = set(b)
common_keys = aset & bset
a_only_keys = aset - bset
b_only_keys = bset - aset

c = dict( (k,a[k]) for k in a_only_keys )
c.update( (k,b[k]) for k in b_only_keys )
c.update( (k,a[k]+b[k]) for k in common_keys )
```

Comment: that was quick :) how do i go about it if they dont share all the keys (just a  few of them)?

Comment: It's too late, but: `{key: a.get(key, []) + b.get(key, []) for key in set(a) | set(b)}`

Comment: @kalgasnik -- True.  You could even avoid the set creation by `a.viewkeys() | b.viewkeys()`  (`a.keys() | b.keys()` for python3.x)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> class ListAccumulator(Counter):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...         return []
... 
>>> a = {'I': [1,2], 'II': [1,2], 'III': [1,2]}
>>> b = {'I': [3,4], 'II': [3,4], 'IV': [3,4]}
>>> 
>>> ListAccumulator(a) + ListAccumulator(b)
Counter({'IV': [3, 4], 'I': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'II': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'III': [1, 2]})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = {'I': [1,2], 'II': [1,2]}
>>> b = {'I': [3,4], 'II': [3,4]}
>>> {key:a[key]+b[key] for key in a}
{'I': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'II': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Note that this only works if they share keys exactly.

Comment: that was quick :) how do i go about it if they dont share all the keys (just a  few of them)?

Comment: Nevermind- those are both better approaches than the `if`s-galore junk I was working on.