# Merging dictionaries from a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, merge, dictionary

I have created a list of dictionaries where each dictionary has a value in the form of list as represented below:

```
dictlist=[{a:['e','f','g'],b:['h','i','k'],c:['u','v',w]},{a:['t','u']}]
```

The above example contains two dictionaries in the list :

```
one is {a:['e','f','g'],b:['h','i','k'],c:['u','v',w]} 
and another dictionary is {a:['t','u']}
```

All i want is to combine the elements of this list so as to produce one complete dictionary with same keys and values in list, as follows :

```
finaldictionary = {a:['e','f','g','t','u'],b:['h','i',k],c:['u','v','w']}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634452/merging-two-dictionaries-with-nested-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'old-school' solution would be something like this...

```
finaldict = {}
dictlist = [{'a': ['e','f','g'], 'b': ['h','i','k'], 'c': ['u','v','w']},
            {'a': ['t','u']}]
for d in dictlist:
    for k in d.keys():
        try:
            finaldict[k] += d[k]
        except KeyError:
            finaldict[k] = d[k]
```

...which would probably work on all versions of Python since v1.0 but there are many newer ways to do it.

Comment: And we all need to support Python 1.0 with our solutions! :P

Comment: @jamylak That's mostly because I started using Python 15 years ago. Besides, if the OP doesn't specify which version he's using, it's less hassle for me than dealing with a followup comment like "That gives me `ImportError: no module named collections`" :P

Comment: props for being an old-school python user but I think we can safely assume everybody uses 2.7+, maybe 1% of OPs use 2.6 but none lower than that

Comment: Just wondering, do you know when `dict.get` came along? (which python version). It's been there since `2.0` for sure.... I guess you could have used that but it might not be `1.0` compatible

Comment: @jamylak Sure. The other point was that the first half of the other answer had already been posted, which I'd already commented wasn't quite right, and there was no point in me posting the same answer. As for `dict.get`, I vaguely recall using it in v1.5, but I'm not certain. Edit: it's in the v1.5 [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5/lib/node13.html).

Comment: Alright cool, well now we just hope someone using Python `1.0` finds this... Ah yes you're right, so 1.5 it is

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> dic=defaultdict(list)

>>> dictlist=[{'a':['e','f','g'],'b':['h','i','k'],'c':['u','v','w']},{'a':['t','u']}]

>>> for x in dictlist:
    for k,v in x.items():
        dic[k].extend(v)

>>> dic
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['e', 'f', 'g', 't', 'u'], 'c': ['u', 'v', 'w'], 'b': ['h', 'i', 'k']})
```

or using `dict.setdefault`:

```
>>> dic={}

>>> for x in dictlist:
        for k,v in x.items():
            dic.setdefault(k,[]).extend(v)

>>> dic
{'a': ['e', 'f', 'g', 't', 'u'], 'b': ['h', 'i', 'k'], 'c': ['u', 'v', 'w']}
```

Comment: Problem with this is that key misses on the output dict would erroneously return the empty list.

Comment: @Aya My second solution solution will work in that case.

Comment: True, but that edit came after I posted the comment. ;-)

Comment: Good answer, but I'm wondering where these `In [16]`'s come from and how are they supposed to be helpful for anyone.

Comment: @thg435 I've replaced those `In[]`,`Out[]`'s with the traditional `>>>` used by the normal interpreter. If you're still wondering then have a look at [IPython](http://ipython.org/) interpreter.